# Tortoise SVN - No error occurred

Tags: tortoise-svn

When I am trying to take SVN update/SVN Commit, I am getting a error message box saying 'No error occurred'.And unable to perform the selected operation.

How can I solve this?

Version

```
TortoiseSVN 1.5.3, Build 13783 - 32 Bit , 2008/08/30 20:59:46
Subversion 1.5.2, 
apr 1.2.12
apr-utils 1.2.12
berkeley db 4.4.20
neon 0.28.3
OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
zlib 1.2.3
```

Comment: Can you you list the version of both the server and the client?

Comment: Well, i guess no error occurred then. ;)

Comment: Version Details                                                        TortoiseSVN 1.5.3, Build 13783 - 32 Bit , 2008/08/30 20:59:46
Subversion 1.5.2, 
apr 1.2.12
apr-utils 1.2.12
berkeley db 4.4.20
neon 0.28.3
OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
zlib 1.2.3

Comment: That would be the client only, not the server as requested. And your TortoiseSVN is now almost 7 years old. Time to upgrade?